# MVC - Return View(Model) cuando hago un POST

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

tengo el siguiente problema.

Mi Controller tiene 2 Funciones. Esta:

```
<AllowAnonymous, HttpGet>
    Function Register(urlBack As String) As ActionResult
        Try
            Dim DBIvas As New BLIva()
            Dim DBProvincias As New BLProvincia()

            ViewBag.CondicionesIva = DBIvas.TraeTodos(Nothing, Nothing, "IdIva")
            ViewBag.Provincias = DBProvincias.TraeTodos(Nothing, "Activo=1 AND IdPais=1", "Descripcion")
            ViewBag.urlBack = urlBack

            If Request.IsAuthenticated Then 'Usuario LOGGEADO
                Dim Model As RegisterViewModel = ModelToModel(Usuario, New RegisterViewModel)

                Dim DBLocalidades As New BLLocalidad
                ViewBag.Localidades = DBLocalidades.TraeTodos(Nothing, "Activo=1 AND IdProvincia=" & Model.IdProvincia, "Descripcion")

                Dim DBBarrios As New BLBarrio
                ViewBag.Barrios = DBBarrios.TraeTodos(Nothing, "Activo=1 AND IdLocalidad=" & Model.IdLocalidad, "Descripcion")

                Return View(Model)
            End If

            Return View()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
```

y esta:

```
<HttpPost, AllowAnonymous, ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
        Function Register(Model As RegisterViewModel, urlBack As String) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                Dim Cliente As mdlCliente = ModelToModel(Model, New mdlCliente)
                If DBClientes.RegistrarUsuarioWeb(Cliente) Then
                    Return Redirect(urlBack)
                Else
                    'Agrego el ERROR.
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ID_ERROR", "El proceso fallo, intentelo de nuevo.")
                End If
            Else
                'Agrego el ERROR.
                Dim FirstError As KeyValuePair(Of String, ModelState) = ModelState.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                ModelState.AddModelError("ID_ERROR", FirstError.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage)
            End If

            'Otros datos necesarios para la VIEW()
            Dim DBIvas As New BLIva()
            Dim DBProvincias As New BLProvincia()

            ViewBag.CondicionesIva = DBIvas.TraeTodos(Nothing, Nothing, "IdIva")
            ViewBag.Provincias = DBProvincias.TraeTodos(Nothing, "Activo=1 AND IdPais=1", "Descripcion")
            ViewBag.urlBack = urlBack

            If Model.IdProvincia <> Nothing Then
                Dim DBLocalidades As New BLLocalidad
                ViewBag.Localidades = DBLocalidades.TraeTodos(Nothing, "Activo=1 AND IdProvincia=" & Model.IdProvincia, "Descripcion")

                If Model.IdLocalidad <> Nothing Then
                    Dim DBBarrios As New BLBarrio
                    ViewBag.Barrios = DBBarrios.TraeTodos(Nothing, "Activo=1 AND IdLocalidad=" & Model.IdLocalidad, "Descripcion")
                End If
            End If

            Return View(Model)
        End Function
```

Cuando el ModelState.IsValid devuelve False o falla la funcion RegistrarUsuarioWeb()

La funcion httpPost devuelve View(Model).

Esta es mi VIEW

```
<div id="content">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <a href="/Home/Index">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li>Registrarse / Ingresar</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="login-partial" class="box">
            @Html.Action("_Login", "Account", New With {.urlBack = urlBack})                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div Class="col-md-12">
        <div Class="box">
            @if Request.IsAuthenticated Then

            Else
                @<p Class="lead">¿Aún no es un usuario registrado?</p>
                @<h1> Registrarse</h1>
                @<p> Registrate y accede a increibles descuentos, promociones y productos! El proceso es gratuito y no te llevara mas que unos minutos!</p>
                @<hr />
            End If

            @Using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "formRegister", .class = IIf(Request.IsAuthenticated, "disabled", "")}))
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.Hidden("urlBack", urlBack)

                @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                @Html.ValidationMessage("ID_ERROR", New With {.class = "text-danger"})

                @<div Class="row">
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.Mail)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Mail, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Mail, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.ClaveWeb)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.ClaveWeb, New With {.class = "form-control", .type = "password"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.ClaveWeb, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-9">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.RazonSocial, "Razon Social/Apellido y Nombre")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.RazonSocial, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.RazonSocial, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-3">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.Telefono, "Telefono/Celular")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Telefono, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Telefono, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.IdIva, "Cond. de IVA")
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.IdIva, New SelectList(CondicionesIva, "IdIva", "Descripcion"), New With {.id = "cmbIva", .class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.IdIva, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.CUIT)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.CUIT, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.CUIT, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                @<hr />
                @<div Class="row">
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.IdProvincia, "Provincia")
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.IdProvincia, New SelectList(Provincias, "IdProvincia", "Descripcion"), New With {.id = "cmbProvincia", .class = "form-control", .onchange = "LoadLocalidades();"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.IdProvincia, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.IdLocalidad, "Localidad")
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.IdLocalidad, New SelectList(Localidades, "IdLocalidad", "Descripcion"), New With {.id = "cmbLocalidad", .class = "form-control", .disabled = "", .onchange = "LoadBarrios();"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.IdLocalidad, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.IdBarrio, "Barrio")
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.IdBarrio, New SelectList(Barrios, "IdBarrio", "Descripcion"), New With {.id = "cmbBarrio", .class = "form-control", .disabled = ""})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.IdBarrio, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                @<div class="row">
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.Calle)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Calle, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Calle, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.Nro)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Nro, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Nro, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.Piso)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Piso, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Piso, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                         @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.Dpto)
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Dpto, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Dpto, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                     </div>
                    <div Class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.Cp)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Cp, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Cp, Nothing, New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                @<hr />
                @<div Class="text-center">
                    @If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
                        @<Button type="submit" Class="btn btn-primary"><i Class="fa fa-user-md"></i>Actualizar</Button>
                    Else
                        @<Button type="submit" Class="btn btn-primary"><i Class="fa fa-user-md"></i>Registrarse</Button>
                    End If
                </div>
            End Using                    
            <hr />
            <p Class="text-muted">Si tienes alguna duda o pregunta, por favor, <a href="/Home/Contact">contactenos</a>, nuestros vendedores estan para atenderlo!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Cuando termina de armar la vista, en vez de dibujarla, me muestra el código fuente como si fuese la pagina Web.

No se si me explico, o pongo una Imagen.

Comment: agrega una imagen para tener de referencia, bienvenido al sitio por cierto :D

Comment: Hola. Pero esta vista  no tiene asignado un Layout verdad? Lo digo porque si es asi te faltan las etiquetas de <html>, <head> y <body>.

Comment: Adjunta una imagen y si puede el archivo de la vista

Comment: Sería bueno ver la imagen del navegador de como renderiza "el codigo fuente". Porque tal vez pueda ser problema del motor de vista. Por las dudas puedes colocar tu global.asax? La parte de Application_Start?

Answer (score 1):

Si el ModelState falla no veo para que defines la linea

```
 Dim FirstError As KeyValuePair(Of String, ModelState) = ModelState.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
```

eso y asignar el `ModelState.AddModelError()` estan de mas, simplemente debes hacer circular la ejecucion hacia el `return View(Model)` sin mas nada que tocar.

En la view defines un `Html.ValidationSummary()` con eso alcanza para mostrarte los mensajes por el cual la validacion del model fallaron. Podrias ver de quitar el parametro `true` (o especificar un false) para que liste todos los errores.

Si el metodo `RegistrarUsuarioWeb()` falla tendras un Exception pero no veo ningun try..catch que lo controles, por lo qu tendras la pagina de error de asp.net mvc.